# Are there names in the Gen ch. 5 genealogy which are derivative of the similar names in the Gen ch. 4 genealogy or viceversa?

Tags: genesis, genealogy, onomastics

The Gen ch. 5 genealogy seems to have been built from the Gen ch. 4 genealogy by repeating the pair (Adam - Cain) as (Enosh - Kenan), slightly changing 3 names, and then switching the positions of Enoch and Mahalalel. My question to users who are familiar with Biblical Hebrew is: is the case in any of the 3 pairs of similar names (Irad, Jared), (Mehujael, Mahalalel), (Methusael, Methuselah) that one name seems more "natural" and the other seems to have been constructed from it?

E.g., in contemporary English both "Edward" and "Edgar" are "natural" names, but ["Eddard" is clearly constructed from "Edward"](https://nameberry.com/babyname/eddard).

EDIT: I am **not** asking about whether or how one genealogy could have been the base for the other. I am asking **only** whether, in each of the 3 pairs of names, one name sounds more "natural" or "plausible" in Biblical Hebrew whereas the other sounds as having been artificially made up from the former (where the "natural" name may in principle be either that of ch. 4 or that of ch. 5).

Comment: The two genealogies have two names in common: Lamech and Enoch.  Apart from that, the others are quite different and have different meanings.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than ch. 5 being built on the foundation of the ch. 4 genealogy, source critics tend to see two separate traditions which were later woven into the text by the ultimate compiler. Also chapter 5 was probably a longer work --"The Book of the Generations of Adam (5.1)--which was the source of several of the genealogies in Genesis. But this does not rule out the ch. 4 material being used in the way suggested. For example, ch. 5 could be based on a similar oral tradition as ch. 4; or it could have used the current ch. 4 as one of its sources. The author may have changed the spellings and order based on his other sources and current usage. (This source is thought to be be compiled after the Babylonian Exile while the source of the chapter 4 material is much earlier.)

The Interpreter's Bible One-Volume Commentary says of chapter 4's version that this section:

> "does not agree in detail the narrative of chapter three and probably
> therefore derives from a different source tradition which the [J author](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Yahwist-source)
> incorporated into his material."

Regarding the genealogy in ch. 5:

> (This) is the sequence to the [P account](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/Bible/King_James/Documentary_Hypothesis/Priestly_source_(Division_1_of_4)) of the creation in chs. 1-2.
> "This is the book of generations of..." was doubtless the original
> title of an actual book, from which the genealogical formula repeated
> at 6:9; 10:1; 11:10; 27, [etc.] may derive.

The importance of genealogies to the P source is dissed [here](https://webpages.scu.edu/ftp/cmurphy/courses/sctr015/prep/exercises/priestly.htm#contents):

> Genealogies feature prominently in the Priestly strands of the Torah.
> Being able to trace a consistent lineage establishes purity,
> legitimacy and order, and is particularly important for the priesthood
> if the relationship with God is to be maintained properly... The Priestly source
> will offer many other genealogies beyond just that of the priesthood,
> as it seeks to (re-)establish a history and a hierarchy after the
> chaos of exile.

**Conclusion: The genealogy of chapter 5 was probably a separate, much longer, document from the one in chapter 4. It is possible that the author of the longer document used the chapter 4 material and slightly changed the names and order as mentioned in the OP; or that he simply had other sources, including oral ones. An even later writer then split up this genealogy and inserted it into the appropriate locations in our current text of Genesis.**

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is off the scope of my question. I am asking only about the 3 pairs of names, independently of whether they come from genealogies. I edited the question to clarify its scope.